# Eject key not working after reinstalling windows

Tags: windows-7, dell-studio

Eject key(cd/dvd) in keyboard(Dell Studio 1557) not working after reinstalling windows.

how can solve this problem?

Comment: Do any of the touch sensitive buttons work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed [Dell QuickSet](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads) program and this work!

Answer (score 1):

SATA controller must be set to AHCI mode and QUICKSET must be installed

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that it's a software problem?
You could verify this by pressing the eject button while the system is booting up. Or boot up a from a Live-Linux (from USB stick) and test it.
If it doesn't work either, your eject button may be broken.

If it's really a windows problem, try booting in fail-safe mode and see if it works then.
If the button works then, the problem is an application that runs in normal mode but not in fail-safe mode. Try to run with as few applications as possible running at once in normal mode.

Maybe some CD/DVD writing applications are blocking the device. You could try to disable/uninstall those, too.

Answer (score 0):

THere's a setting in BIOS. I changed mine from Multimedia first to Function first. Worked fine after that. Also installed QuickSet though and ensured AHCI was set which it was already.